# React router dom v6 - navigate(-1) need to press 2 time when refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm using `react` with `react-router-dom` v6. I found that when I navigate to 1 page, and in that page if I refresh the page the button invoke `navigate(-1)` needs to be pressed 2 times and the time it need to press to goback the last page increase with how many time I refresh that page.

So any idea to fix that even how many time I refresh the page `navigate(-1)` will always go back to the last page?

```
import { CButton } from '@coreui/react-pro';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductionStatisticsManagement = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      ProductionStatisticsManagement
      <CButton onClick={() => navigate('/production-statistics/update')}>Redirect</CButton>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductionStatisticsManagement;
```

...

```
import { CButton } from '@coreui/react-pro';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductionStatisticsUpdate = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleCountNavigate = () => {
    navigate(-1);
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  return (
    <>
      ProductionStatisticsUpdate Button press:{count}
      <CButton onClick={handleCountNavigate}>Redirect</CButton>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductionStatisticsUpdate;
```

Comment: Please be more specific or show us the code you're actually using so we can understand your issue.

Comment: I just add some code for the question

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with *this* code. Could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?